# Insert into matching on a WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, update, where

I'm sure this is simple but can't get it work. I have two tables, A and B, where one only A has `ID` and they both have `Number`. I'd like to copy all the ID's from A into B where their `Number` matches (all Number values are unique).

I tried this but I'm getting invalid column name

```
INSERT INTO dbo.B ( [ID] ) 
SELECT orig_id
FROM dbo.A a, dbo.B b
WHERE b.[NUMBER] = a.number
```

but a whole bunch of new rows are created instead of updating the existing ones. How can I update the `ID` column of table B with the id's from table A matching on the `Number` values?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update dbo.B 
set b.[ID] = a.orig_id
FROM dbo.A a
join dbo.B b
on b.[NUMBER] = a.number 
and b.[ID] <> a.orig_id
```

the <> is so it can avoid taking a lock if the are equal